# Wcf classes public property vs property with get;set

Tags: wcf

When creating a wcf class I used to do

```
[DataContract]
Public class Customer
{
      [DataMember]
     public string Name {get;set}
}
```

I have been told that is better to do

```
[DataContract]
Public class Customer
{
      [DataMember]
     public string Name ;    
}
```

basically removing the get and set as will be lighter

Is this the case?

any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use auto-properties (using only get; set; and no backing variable), a member variable is generated randomly (you can use Reflector or ILDASM to see it). This variable, depending on the serialization scheme could be serialized.

If you rebuild, member variable name **could** be re-generated which can cause error in de-serialising objects serialised using old DLL. In the same way, a DLL shipped to the customer could have the OLD generated member variable so WCF communication could throw exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Are you saying that is better to use public with no get and no setters.Or are you saying that I should use properties with backing field? no sure of your answer.

Comment: I have updated and made it clearer. Auto properties is the one with get; set; and not the classic one.

Comment: thanks what about public fields then.Is wrong and why?Same reasons?

Comment: Yes, because they are serialised differently and generally not a good thing to do.